Proof of the way to proceed when you fail to find a particular solution of 2nd order linear ODE
I was reading a math for economics book and it says the following:

Example 4.11 Find the particular solution of $y''-y'-6y=e^{3t}$
It is reasonable to think that $y_p=Ae^{3t}$. However, after replacing the function and its respective derivatives in the ODE we get $$9Ae^{3t}-3Ae^{3t}-6Ae^{3t}=e^{3t}$$ or $0=e^{3t}$ which is a contradiction. What happened? The method failed? The problem in this case is that $y=Ae^{3t}$ is the complementary solution $y''-y'-6y=0$, which makes impossible for $y_p$ to satisfy the ODE, whichever is the value of A. How to proceed? Evidence shows us that multiplying $Ae^{3t}$ by $t$ produces good results...

The book shows the proof of the solution for a second order homogenous ODE so I think that´s why it says "evidence shows us that multiplying $Ae^{3t}$ by $t$ produces good results" (it shows why when the roots of the characteristic polynomial is reapeted twice, the solution has the form $y=e^{rt}(C_1t+C_2)$ and the proof for the other cases). The author of the book is my Math for economics´s teacher and today in class he said to just believe him and that the proof of why we should multiply by $t$ everytime we fail to find a particular solution is not important.
Where can I find said proof? Is there any book/online resource that shows why multiplying by $t$ is needed? I´ve been searching it but I can´t find anything.
PD: The book and the course only focuses in the case $y''+a_1y'+a_0y=b(t)$ where $a_o$ and $a_1$ are known constants

There is a book called "Differential Equations with Boundary-Value problems" (Denis G. Zill and Michael R. Cullen). The fourth chapter talks about high order differential equations. The section of undetermined coefficients could be useful for you.

Thanks, I will take a look at it

In any elementary text on differential equations look for the phrase "variation of constants". Start with the first-order case $y'-3y=\exp(3t)$ which presents essentially the same problem as your second-order equation.

There are many ways to establish the 'correct' guess for the particular integral. Although, don't forget that solving differential equations is really often just guessing a solution, seeing if it works and then slapping it with a relevant uniqueness theorem. We could guess a particular integral of the form $y_p(t) = f(t) e^{3t}$ for some function $f$, and obtained the guess from there. But let's see how we might have been inspired to come up with the guess more directly.
The first is by detuning. To remove the degeneracy, let us modify the differential equation slightly to $$y'' - y' - 6y = e^{(3 + \varepsilon)t},$$
which reduces to the original equation in the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$. We try a particular integral $y_p = Ae^{(3 + \varepsilon)t}$, which gives $$A(3 + \epsilon)^2 - A(3 + \varepsilon) - 6A = 1 \implies A = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2 +5\varepsilon}.$$
Unfortunately, this has no finite limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$. But we can fix this by adding in some solution of the homogeneous equation, as this will still be a valid particular integral. Then,
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{e^{(3+\varepsilon)t} - e^{3t}}{\varepsilon^2 + 5 \varepsilon} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{t e^{(3+\varepsilon)t}}{2 \varepsilon + 5} = \frac{1}{5} te^{3t}.$$
Another method is by variation of parameters. One can show (and you should) that for the inhomogeneous equation $y'' + P(t) y' + q(t)y = f(t)$ with linearly independent complementary functions $y_1$ and $y_2$, we have a particular integral
$$y_p(t) = y_2(t) \int^t \frac{y_1(\xi) f(\xi)}{W(\xi)} \, \mathrm d\xi - y_1(t) \int^t \frac{y_2(\xi) f(\xi)}{W(\xi)} \, \mathrm d\xi,$$
where $W$ is the Wronskian $W = y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2$.
(This is really a disguised Green's function in action.) In our case, we have a Wronskian $- 2e^{3t} - e^{-2t} + 3 e^{3t} e^{-2t} = -5 e^t$, so
\begin{align*}
y_p(x) &= -\frac 15 e^{-2t} \int^x \frac{e^{3t} e^{3t}}{e^t} + \frac 15 e^{3t} \int^t \frac{e^{-2t} e^{3t}}{e^t} \\
&= \frac 15 te^{3t} - e^{3t}
\end{align*}
But the second term is a multiple of one of the complementary functions, so we again obtain the particular integral $\frac 15 te^{3t}$.

Hi, thanks for the answer, I didn´t know about the variation of parameters method and spent a couple hours learning/understanding/practicing it yesterday. However, for the detuning method, why you decided to add a $e^{(3+\epsilon)t}-e^{3t}$ in the numerator of the limit? the limit of $e^{(3+\epsilon)t}-e^{3t}$ isn´t 1 so I don´t understand the reason behind replacing $1$ with something that its limit is 0.

There are a few ways to derive the form of the particular solution, e.g., variation of parameters, integral transforms, operator methods. But I'll go through a limiting procedure. Suppose we start with the problem $$y''-y'-6y=e^{\lambda t}$$
The homogeneous equation has solutions $e^{3t},e^{-2t}$. A particular solution $y_p=Ae^{\lambda t}$ is then independent of these homogeneous solutions so long as $\lambda\neq -2,3$, and indeed we have $$y_p''-y_p'-6y_p=(\lambda^2-\lambda-6)Ae^{\lambda t}=(\lambda-3)(\lambda+2)Ae^{(a+3)t}$$
Hence $A=(\lambda-3)^{-1}(\lambda+2)^{-1}$ and the particular solution is $$y_p =\dfrac{e^{\lambda t}}{(\lambda-3)(\lambda+2)}$$ Now let $h=\lambda -3$. If we expand this solution for small $h$, we have
\begin{align}
y_p=\frac{e^{ht}e^{3t}}{h(5+h)}
&=\frac{e^{3t}}{5h}\left(1-\frac{h}{5}-\frac{h^2}{25}-\cdots\right)\left(1+ht+\frac{h^2 t^2}{2}+\cdots \right)\\
&\approx \frac{e^{3t}}{5}\left[\frac{1}{h}+\left(t-\frac{1}{5}\right) \right]\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{h}-\frac{1}{5}\right)e^{3t}+t e^{3t}
\end{align}
The first term is a multiple of a homogeneous solution and can thus be absorbed into that part of the general solution . Hence in the limit $h\to 0$ the solution the appropriate particular solution is indeed $te^{3t}$.

Just beat me to it! Nice solution.

Maybe an alternate method of solution will help to show how a $t$ gets introduced into the particular solution of this problem.  You may have already learned to use integrating factors to solve first order linear differential equations, but they can be used in cases such as this as well.  We have
$$y''-y'-6y=y''+2y'-3y'-6y=(y'+2y)'-3(y'+2y)$$
Substituting $u=y'+2y$ gives $u'-3u=e^{3t}$.  Multiplying both sides by an integrating factor of $e^{-3t}$ gives
$$(e^{-3t}u)'=1$$
$$e^{-3t}u=t+C$$
$$u=te^{-3t}+Ce^{-3t}$$
Something similar also happens if the characteristic equation has repeated roots.
